# Adding widget to layout specified in QString

Tags: qt

I started my first steps programming in Qt and can't find an answer.
I have some widget, let's say it's named "tab".
I want to add to it's layout new widget.
I can do it by writing:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(tab);
```

I want to do the same thing , but instead of saying "tab" I want to use widget name stored in QString variable. Something like this (but it doesn't work, can't convert QString to QWidget):

```
QString name = "tab";
QLabel *label = new label(zakladka);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: That's not possible. Variable names are not interchangeable with strings. Maybe you can explain what you're trying to do, and we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: I have few tabs. 
I want to read tab name from text file and place an object on that specific tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QObjects have a property `objectName`.  So if you name your objects and have them be part of a hierarchy of QObject (i.e. you know they are children of a parent object) you can make use of [findChild](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild)

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(parentWidget->findChild(name));
```